# HTML PDFplugin: possible to get an event in Javascript when the page is changed by clicking PDF links or bookmarks?

Tags: html, pdf, plugins, dom-events

I know it is possible to have a PDFplugin embedded in a HTML page to display a PDF file inside a browser. For example it works in IE with OBJECT id="pdf" type="application/pdf" ...

I ask if it is possible to connect a Javascript function with an event raised by the PDFplugin when page is changed by the inside of the plugin, for example by clicking on bookmarks or links, reporting also the new page.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have control over the PDF content? If you do, I believe you can add some script to take care of the navigation changes within the PDF document.

However if you are just serving up the PDF (e.g. you can't/didn't modify the PDF content to provide a hook) then I think you are stuck as the browser will not know what the user is doing within the PDF file.

Presuming you have access to the PDF content and can inject scripting into it then you can use the API here: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf to trap events like the Init, Bookmark, Mouseup, Mousedown, Focus, Blur, Keystroke, etc.

Comment: The PDF file is any, so it has not a script inside. Furthermore I am searching for a solution without putting a script into Adobe Reader folders to have Adobe app level scripts (if possible for the plugin). But however, just to know, if I put an app level script how would the Javascript inside the plugin communicate with the HTML javascript?

Comment: There is a few options.  To tell if the PDF is embedded in a browser, `if(this.external)` will return `true` if it is.  Communication to/from the browser can be done using the `HostContainer` Object. page 486 in the API linked above.

Comment: Do you mean this statement "This property allows a script running in the web browser scripting context to register a notification object 
that will be called if a script in the PDF document calls the Doc hostContainer.postMessage method."?